# CSS issue in Chrome for Android

Tags: android, css, mobile, responsive-design, viewport

I'm developing a very basic responsive website.
While it works perfectly on the Responsinator and Firefox for Android, some of the media queries and CSS properties don't seem to be taken into account by Chrome when I run the website on my Nexus 4.

I'm using a viewport placed on each page in the , could this be the issue?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Here is the media query at the screen-size causing trouble:

```
@media (max-width: 490px) {
#welcome {
    background-size: 16em 11em;
}
h1 a {
    width: 70.6%;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    /*padding-top: 16px;*/
    padding-top: 0.7em;
}
h2.pageTitle {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    margin: 25% auto 10px auto;
}
p.pageDescription {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 85%;
}
p.pageDescription:last-child {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto 26% auto;
}
.workThumbnail {
    height: 140px;
}
p.workThumbnailDescription {
    font-size: 1em;
}
footer {height: 100%;}
p.currentStatus {font-size: 1.6em;}
p.copyright {font-size: 0.8em;}
/* Movie Poster Page */
#OMthePostersEditorial {
    width: 85%;
}
/* CAG Page */
#CAGourGoal {float: none;}
#CAGourGoalEditorial {
    width: 85%;
}
h2.caseStudyTitle {}
p.caseStudyDescription {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
strong.titleItalic {
    font-size: 1em;
}
/* Contact Page */
section.formContainer {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10% 0 10% 0;
}
#contactForm {
    display: none;
}
#contactMobile {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 230px;
}
#contactMobile a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLight';
    color: #252626;
}
```

}

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `width` in the meta - content:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't do it. Nothing changed. Thank you though.

Comment: Sure, I added it to the question. I did not join the HTML since it is not causing the issue (everything works all right on Firefox Android)

Comment: hmm, it's hard to say what could be the problem, but the best way is to use the PHONEGAP DEBUGGER: http://debug.phonegap.com/ . Check if your media query rules is overwritten by any other rule or what happening. If you're familiar with the Chrome Developer Tools, than it will be easy. Good luck